# How to run a backend server with Node?

Tags: node.js, backend

I am learning Vue.js and from the basic template `vue init webpack my-project`, I would like to have a backend running.

The frontend is launched using `webpack`, but my `server.js` file have to be started separately using `node server.js`. How can I start them together?

I searched for some basic examples, but they are hard to find.

Currently I have in my `package.json` this:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "client": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",

    "server": "nodemon src/server/server.js --exec babel-node"
  },
  // ...
}
```

This is great, but the client and the server run on different ports. On the production application I would need to use only one port.

How is it possible?

Comment: In production or development?

Comment: I would say in development

Comment: [`concurrently`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently)? Have a look [here](https://github.com/textbook/cyf-library/blob/c15a630198f6a3142606d98fce721290c338f964/package.json#L18) where `yarn dev` starts a React dev server and the Express backend in parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In production environment**

Here is my usual deployment strategy

> I use Nginx as a static web server and HTTP proxy
>
> I use [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/) to mange  node API

PM2 is great process manager tool with several features

> So what you need to is build (probably `npm run build`) your vue js
>   app then you will get your static assets a dist/build folder
>   containing just static content with index.html as an entry point

Start your node server with pm2 like the following

```
pm2 start server.js --name='api'
```

Here is a sample Nginx configuration proxying the node API and serving the static content it's found at  `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
server {
    listen *:80;

    server_name localhost; ## could be  www.yourdomain.com

    location / {
          root /home/me/myapp/dist; # your app build path
          try_files $uri index.html;
      }
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5678/api;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_connect_timeout 600000;
        proxy_send_timeout 600000;
        proxy_read_timeout 600000;
        send_timeout 600000;

        gzip on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_types
            application/json;

    }
```

> So what you basically get is your Vue app at port 80 the default so
>   you don't have to specify the port and your API will be at /api   so
>   your vue app will be at **youdomain.com** and the API at
>   **youdomain.com/api**

**In development environment**

I usually don't mind starting my API and frontend with two commands. 
I so start them in a separate terminal to debug and develop separately.

```
if you really care about starting them in the single command
```

What you could do is create a new command in your package.json

```
"start":"npm run server && npm run client"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/)

PM2 is a process management tool to start, stop and monitor Node JS applications.

Read this guide how to Simultaneously Running Express and Webpack Dev Server.

[Simultaneously Running Express and Webpack Dev Server](https://medium.com/dailyjs/vue-js-simultaneously-running-express-and-webpack-dev-server-292f4a7ed7a3)

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.  This will still cause there to be 2 running node processes plus you'll have the overhead of PM2.

Comment: Actually it does answer the question. With this solution I am able to run my backend. But I still don't know how I can easily debug it...

Comment: Is it possible to have both the client and the server on the same port?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of an opinion but; idealy, your front end and back end should exist separately.  But if you find it easier to have a combined codebase where starting one starts the other, you can consider leveraging [webpack-dev-middleware](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware).

When you say that you have separate `server.js` file, it sounds like you want to be able to hang additional middleware off of server that webpack sets up.  `webpack-dev-middleware` exposes a server for you to hang whatever middleware on that you want which means 1 server rather than 2 node instances.

I have tried doing this before, but the main issue that I ran into is that if I made changes to my actual server, I would need to restart webpack which can take a while to actually start, but is much faster whenever hot reloading is used since the whole process isn't restarting constantly.

Do note though that your front end, unless you're using something like nuxt, will just be static content after you run `npm build`.  You won't be running `webpack` in production.

Comment: why it`s not possible on production?

Comment: @ReenaMori because, unless you are using server side rendering, webpack will generate a static bundle that will no longer need webpack to be running to work.

Comment: @zero298 So you might think that Meteor is not a good solution?

Comment: I don't really understand what is `webpack-dev-middleware`.